# Validating a Textbox field for only numeric input.

Tags: c#, validation, textbox

I have created a form-based program that needs some input validation.  I need to make sure the user can only enter numeric values within the distance Textbox.

So far, I've checked that the Textbox has something in it, but if it has a value then it should proceed to validate that the entered value is numeric:

```
else if (txtEvDistance.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the distance");
        }
else if (cboAddEvent.Text //is numeric)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid numeric distance");
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by numeric? Only digits? Valid decimal?

Comment: I mean, values greater than 0, and integer, typical sporting event distances

Comment: Very similar question, may be duplicate.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357150/exception-while-converting-string-to-integer-in-c-sharp/10357327#10357327

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may try the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) method which allows you to parse a string into an integer and return a boolean result indicating the success or failure of the operation.

```
int distance;
if (int.TryParse(txtEvDistance.Text, out distance))
{
    // it's a valid integer => you could use the distance variable here
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to prevent the user from enter non-numeric values at the time of enter the information in the TextBox, you can use the Event OnKeyPress like this:

```
private void txtAditionalBatch_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) e.Handled = true;         //Just Digits
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)8) e.Handled = false;            //Allow Backspace
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) btnSearch_Click(sender, e);  //Allow Enter            
        }
```

This solution doesn't work if the user paste the information in the TextBox using the mouse (right click / paste) in that case you should add an extra validation.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another simple **solution**

```
try
{
    int temp=Convert.ToInt32(txtEvDistance.Text);
}
catch(Exception h)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please provide number only");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by *javascript* on client side or using some regex **validator** on the textbox.

### Javascript

```
script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function validateNumbersOnly(e) {
        var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
        if ((unicode == 8) || (unicode == 9) || (unicode > 47 && unicode < 58)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {

            window.alert("This field accepts only Numbers");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

### Textbox (with fixed ValidationExpression)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator6" runat="server" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Accepts only numbers." ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$" Text="*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure it window forms

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way

```
   // Check if the point entered is numeric or not
   if (Int32.TryParse(txtEvDistance.Text, out var outParse))
    {
       // Do what you want to do if numeric
    }
   else
    {
       // Do what you want to do if not numeric
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Int.TryParse but as an alternative you could use Regex.

```
 Regex nonNumericRegex = new Regex(@"\D");
 if (nonNumericRegex.IsMatch(txtEvDistance.Text))
 {
   //Contains non numeric characters.
   return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this extension which is kind of multi-purpose:

```
    public static bool IsNumeric(this object value)
    {
        if (value == null || value is DateTime)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (value is Int16 || value is Int32 || value is Int64 || value is Decimal || value is Single || value is Double || value is Boolean)
        {
            return true;
        }

        try
        {
            if (value is string)
                Double.Parse(value as string);
            else
                Double.Parse(value.ToString());
            return true;
        }
        catch { }
        return false;
    }
```

It works for other data types. Should work fine for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
        if (int.TryParse(txtDepartmentNo.Text, out checkNumber) == false)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = string.Empty;
            lblMessage.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Maroon;
            lblMessage.Text = "You have not entered a number";
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that allows either numeric only with a minus sign or decimal with a minus sign and decimal point.  Most of the previous answers did not take into account selected text.  If you change your textbox's ShortcutsEnabled to false, then you can't paste garbage into your textbox either (it disables right-clicking).  Some solutions allowed you to enter data before the minus.  Please verify that I've caught everything!

```c#
        private bool DecimalOnly_KeyPress(TextBox txt, bool numeric, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (numeric)
            {
                // Test first character - either text is blank or the selection starts at first character.
                if (txt.Text == "" || txt.SelectionStart == 0)
                {
                    // If the first character is a minus or digit, AND
                    // if the text does not contain a minus OR the selected text DOES contain a minus.
                    if ((e.KeyChar == '-' || char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) && (!txt.Text.Contains("-") || txt.SelectedText.Contains("-")))
                        return false;
                    else
                        return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // If it's not the first character, then it must be a digit or backspace
                    if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back))
                        return false;
                    else
                        return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Test first character - either text is blank or the selection starts at first character.
                if (txt.Text == "" || txt.SelectionStart == 0)
                {
                    // If the first character is a minus or digit, AND
                    // if the text does not contain a minus OR the selected text DOES contain a minus.
                    if ((e.KeyChar == '-' || char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) && (!txt.Text.Contains("-") || txt.SelectedText.Contains("-")))
                        return false;
                    else
                    {
                        // If the first character is a decimal point or digit, AND
                        // if the text does not contain a decimal point OR the selected text DOES contain a decimal point.
                        if ((e.KeyChar == '.' || char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) && (!txt.Text.Contains(".") || txt.SelectedText.Contains(".")))
                            return false;
                        else
                            return true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // If it's not the first character, then it must be a digit or backspace OR
                    // a decimal point AND
                    // if the text does not contain a decimal point or the selected text does contain a decimal point.
                    if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back) || (e.KeyChar == '.' && (!txt.Text.Contains(".") || txt.SelectedText.Contains("."))))
                        return false;
                    else
                        return true;
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if the value is a double:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out var x))
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("it's not a double ");
        return;
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine("it's a double ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I figured out I should pitch my answer anyways.

The following snippet iterates through each character of the text and uses the IsNumber() method, which returns true if the character is a number and false the other way, to check if all the characters are numbers. If all are numbers, the method returns true. If not it returns false.

```
using System;

private bool ValidateText(string text){
    char[] characters = text.ToCharArray();

    foreach(char c in characters){
        if(!char.IsNumber(c))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex as below.

```
if (txtNumeric.Text.Length < 0 || !System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtNumeric.Text, "^[0-9]*$")) {
 MessageBox.show("add content");
} else {
 MessageBox.show("add content");
}
```