# C# IF that checks wether a textbox input is greater than 0 and also checks if it's an integer(Numeric)

Tags: c#, if-statement, textbox

I made a scoreboard where the user inputs the max number of points allowed in a textBox1. I have two buttons. The left one increases the value on the left side of a label and the right one increases the value on the right side of the label. Once one side reaches the maximum number of points I declare the winner using a MessageBox.

I want to know how to check if the user didn't input an integer in the textbox. I already made te condition for it to be greater than 0.

This is what I have: [SCOREBOARD IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/024lb.png)

```
public void winner()
{
    int max = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

    if (max <= 0 || //this is where i want to check if its an integer)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Press RESET and use a value greater than 0");
        btn_left.Enabled = false;
        btn_right.Enabled = false;
        textBox1.ResetText();
    }
    else if (left == max)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Winner: Left Player");
        textBox1.Enabled = false;
        btn_left.Enabled = false;
        btn_right.Enabled = false;
    }
    else if (right == max)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Winner: Right Player");
        textBox1.Enabled = false;
        btn_left.Enabled = false;
        btn_right.Enabled = false;
    }
}

private void btn_left_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    left = left + 1;
    lbl_score.Text = left.ToString() + " - " + right.ToString();
    winner();
}

private void btn_right_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    right = right + 1;
    lbl_score.Text = left.ToString() + " - " + right.ToString();
    winner();
}

private void btn_reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Enabled = true;
    textBox1.Text = "0";
    btn_left.Enabled = true;
    btn_left.Enabled = true;
    left = 0;
    right = 0;
    lbl_score.Text = left.ToString() + " - " + right.ToString();
}
```

Edit: I checked the other solution suggested in the comments but none of the answers there seem to work for me except the one I selected in this thread

Comment: `if (int.TryParse(myTextBox.Text, out var _) ? _ > 0 : false) {/* numeric and positive */}`

Comment: Can't you use the numeric updown control? That would fit better I think (as it restricts the input to numbers)

Comment: [Int32.TryParse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation is your friend

Comment: EpicKip How do I do that? Sorry, I just started learning C# very recently

Comment: @ReneVazquez In the toolbox (where all the controls you can place are) do you see something like `NumericUpDown` (not sure of the name). Then when you want the value, just do `.Value`

Comment: Please look at here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/84990ad2-5046-472b-b103-f862bfcd5dbc/how-to-check-string-is-number-or-not-in-c?forum=winforms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating a Textbox field for only numeric input.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401633/validating-a-textbox-field-for-only-numeric-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the text to make sure its a number

```
 public void winner()
 {

      if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out int max))
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Dem numbers aren't numbers");
         return;
      }

      ...
```

[Int32.TryParse Method (String, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion
>   succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

using TryParse for test number input

```
private bool function GreaterNumber(string text)
{
    bool result = Int32.TryParse(myTextBox.Text, out number);
    return result && number > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following lines of code after:

```
int max;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out max);
if (result && max > 0) ...
```

Thanks to @john for the suggestions.

Cheers!

Comment: You might want to change the if to `if (result && max > 0)` so that it matches the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can first check for the integer by using int.TryParse(n, out value) and the check for greater than zero.

```
int value;
bool success=int.TryParse(n, out value);

if(success)
{
if(n>0)
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  string a = textBox1.txt;
  int b;
  bool ans = int.TryParse(a, out b);

  if (ans == true) 
  {
       // your code
  }
  else
  {
      MessageBox.Show("invalid input"). // or whatever you want.
  }
```

If you already declare a, b variables somewhere else please change name.

Comment: You should place this before the line `int max = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.txt)` so if input isn't integer than no need to convert.